# Adding an information icon to a form element

Tags: theming, forms, 8

I currently have a number of form elements that I have added an image icon to, which users can click on or hover over for more information... which looks like this:

*(The blue image icon is the one users hover over for more information)*

[image]

When defining the component via render arrays like so:

```
$component[$this->componentName] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Project Name'),
  '#description' => t('Enter the name of the project'),
  '#description_display' => 'before',
  '#required' => 'True',
);
```

Is there away to get the image icon to sit along side the element (either the title or the description or the textfield), for example like this:

[image]

I am aware that there is the potential to use something like the #attributes tag to add tooltips too (as outlined below), but wondered whether there is scope to add the image icon as I am attempting?

```
'name' => array(
  '#title' => t('Name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 30,
  '#maxlength' => 45,
  '#default_value' => $item->Name,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'title' => t("Item's name, no longer than 45 characters."),
  )
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS/jQuery Solution:

Use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/): the sibling right after selector;

```
var moveEl = ".INFO-ICON";
var moveElementAfter = ".PROJECT-LABEL";

$(moveElementAfter).after( $(moveEl) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and help @Chris Happy , much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'#prefix' => 'Some title <img src="/some/image/source">'` instead of `'#title' => t('Name')`

```
$component[$this->componentName] =  array(
                  '#prefix' => t('Some title*') .' <img src="/some/image/source">',
                  '#type' => 'textfield',
                  '#size' => 30,
                  '#maxlength' => 45,
                  '#default_value' => $item->Name,
                  '#attributes' => array(

                  );
```

You can add any markup to '#prefix' element of this array.

Or you can add markup even directly to title `'#title' => t('Some title*') .'<img src="/sdfsf">'`, but i think there can be some issues with asterisk when a field is required.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out with this @Andrew Nim it was really helpful, in the end I used a variant of this idea with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

A few options come to mind:

1. Simplest would be css pseudo class ':after', and I'm sure with a 'title' attribute and little `js` would be an easy hack.
2. A twig suggestion can get you access to that form element template.
   To start make sure you have `parameters.twig.config: { debug: true
   ...` in your service.yml, in order to see template suggestions in
   your html.

Then you need to add it and `cache:rebuild`:

```
function MODULE_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

$type = isset($variables['element']['#type']) ? 
 $variables['element']['#type'] : '';
$type = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?! ]/", '_', $type);
$suggestions[] = 'form_element__' . $type;
...
 }
```

You will get a template to theme like `form-element--textfield.html.twig` and you can add you variable to that template, or you can add more suggestions based on your $variables,  and you can also get between your form code and this template with `MODULE_preprocess_field(..`

3. A FieldWidget would let you select a different option in your form manager ui. You would need to copy and specify your own annotation of the plugin for the widget in core `/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/StringTextfieldWidget.php`

Comment: Thanks @Dylan for taking the time for helping out with this ... good suggestions and input